# Next.js source maps with typescript on Sentry

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, sentry

I have a simple setup for a project that imitates the [Next JS sentry (simple) example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-sentry-simple)

The problem is without sentry `Enable JavaScript source fetching` feature on, I cannot get the source maps to report correctly to sentry
example: [image]

with the `Enable JavaScript source fetching` it shows correctly
example (of the same error): [image]

Here is the configuration files used:

```
// next.config.js
const { parsed: localEnv } = require("dotenv").config();
const webpack = require("webpack");
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");

// Package.json => "@zeit/next-source-maps": "^0.0.4-canary.1",
const withSourceMaps = require("@zeit/next-source-maps")({ devtool: "source-map" });

module.exports = withSourceMaps({
  target: "serverless",
  env: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    // Sentry DNS configurations
    SENTRY_DNS: process.env.SENTRY_DNS,
  },
  poweredByHeader: false,

  webpack(config, options) {
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(localEnv));
    config.resolve.plugins.push(new TsconfigPathsPlugin());
    config.node = {
      // Fixes node packages that depend on `fs` module
      fs: "empty",
    };

    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.resolve.alias["@sentry/node"] = "@sentry/browser";
    }

    return config;
  },
});
```

The `src/pages/_app.tsx` and `src/pages/_error.tsx` follow the example mentioned in the repo.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@services/*": ["./src/services/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["./src/utils/*"]
    },
    "removeComments": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "sourceRoot": "/",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cypress",
    "test",
    "public",
    "out"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

The source maps are uploaded to sentry during CI build process
Using this script (after `next build` and `next export`)

```
configure-sentry-release.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

# Install Sentry-CLI
curl -sL https://sentry.io/get-cli/ | bash

export SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT="production"
export SENTRY_RELEASE=$(sentry-cli releases propose-version)

# Configure the release and upload source maps
echo "=> Configure Release: $SENTRY_RELEASE :: $SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT"
sentry-cli releases new $SENTRY_RELEASE --project $SENTRY_PROJECT
sentry-cli releases set-commits --auto $SENTRY_RELEASE
sentry-cli releases files $SENTRY_RELEASE upload-sourcemaps ".next" --url-prefix "~/_next" 
sentry-cli releases deploys $SENTRY_RELEASE new -e $SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT
sentry-cli releases finalize $SENTRY_RELEASE
```

Is there anyway to get the source maps to work with sentry (without the `Enable JavaScript source fetching` and without leaving the source map publicly available on the server)?

Comment: You mention `Enable JavaScript source fetching`, could you share a link about what it is and how to enable it? I have a similar need at https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/issues/28 but I haven't ever seen this feature you mention

Comment: Per organization settings: Settings > General > Allow JavaScript Source Fetching (toggle under "Security and Privacy")

per project: Project name > settings > General Settings > Allow JavaScript Source Fetching (toggle under "Client Security")

Comment: I've looked into the source code in your (pretty good) project for reference, but I couldn't find a way to get the source maps to show as the second screenshot (which indicates where the error happens in the tsx file) without enabling source fetching... would really appreciate any help to know how it could be achieved without exposing the source maps publicly... :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be solved by abandoning the `configure-sentry-release.sh` script to upload the source maps manually but instead using [sentry webpack plugin](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin)

```
yarn add @sentry/webpack-plugin
```

and use the plugin with `next.config.js` (webpack) to upload the source maps during the build step

```
// next.config.js
  ...
  webpack(config, options) {
    ...
    // Sentry Webpack configurations for when all the env variables are configured
    // Can be used to build source maps on CI services
    if (SENTRY_DNS && SENTRY_ORG && SENTRY_PROJECT) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new SentryWebpackPlugin({
          include: ".next",
          ignore: ["node_modules", "cypress", "test"],
          urlPrefix: "~/_next",
        }),
      );
    }
    ...
```

More on the issue can be found here:

- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/11642
- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/8873

Answer (score 3):

For anyone landing here in 2022 - the Sentry Next.js SDK now runs the webpack plugin which @a14m mentioned automatically, and there's a wizard to get everything set up.

SDK docs:
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/

Manual setup if you don't want to use the wizard, plus some advanced config options:
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/